# How to define a variable on top level and also assert it , in dart?

Tags: dart

In a dart file, I can define a top level variable by given it a value (or expression):

```
String name = getNameFromSomewhere();
```

But in some case, I need to assert it a valid name, so I want to:

```
String name = {
    String _name = getNameFromSomewhere();
    if(_name == null) {
        throw new Exception("Name is invalid");
    }
    return _name;
}
```

But the syntax is invalid, instead, I have to make it a function and invocation:

```
String name = (() {
    String _name = getNameFromSomewhere();
    if(_name == null) {
        throw new Exception("Name is invalid");
    }
    return _name;
})();
```

But the code is not so readable, is there any way to improve it?

Answer (score 1):

In Dart it isn't necessary to wrap an IIFE in `()` too, so you can clean up the syntax that way.  You can also shadow the `name` binding and skip the private local.  And finally, it is okay to use `var`, assuming that `getNameFromSomewhere()` has an annotated return type, the type will be correctly inferred as a String.

```
String name = () {
 var name = getNameFromSomewhere();
 if (_name == null)
   throw new Exception("Name is invalid");
 return name;
}();
```

Now, depending on what you want to do with this, it *might* not work as you expect.  In Dart all top level members and static fields are lazily initialized. In this case, an exception won't be thrown until `name` is accessed for the first time.  For example, the following code won't throw.

```
void main() {}

String getNameFromSomeWhere() => null;

String name = ...;
```

But this code will

```
void main() {
  print(name);
}

String getNameFromSomeWhere() => null;

String name = ...;
```

Comment: Thanks! It's very useful to know "all top level members and static fields are lazily initialized"

Answer (score 1):

I'd make the initializer a private function, just for readability or override in subclasses:

```
String name = _getValidName();
String _getValidName () {
  var name = _getNameFromSomewhere();
  if (name == null)
    throw new Exception("Name is invalid");
  return name;
};
String _getNameFromSomewhere () { ... }
```